# Is this an optimal way of updating sprites in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

Cutting through all the unrelated parts this is how I implemented it:

```
done=False
while(done==False)
    #here goes some code for listening to the events
    if (some condition fulfilled) then
           screen.blit(background, [0,0])
           screen.blit(some_sprite,[x,y])
      elif (more conditions)
           do something else
      else
           do even more stuff

   pygame.display.flip()
```

Without the background update within this conditional statement this sprite doesn't get deleted, of course, os I get multiple copies on the screen. I have a strong suspicion this is by far not the optimal way of handling the situation, because blitting the image that doesn't change every time I need to do something else seems like a waste of resources.

I would appreciate any suggestions

Comment: do you have a way of knowing what rect the sprite was occupying previously? You could draw that portion of the background with `pygame.draw.rect` rather than the entire background

Comment: or depending on your background, `screen.blit(background, [sprite_old_x, sprite_old_y])`

Comment: that's certainly an option. I suspect though it's by far not the best way. THere should be something involving arrays of sprites, I guess.

Comment: what did you have in mind?

Comment: I 'improved' it a little bit by moving the background update to the event for all mouse movements. But I don't think it's a good solution though.

Comment: the main loop in a pygame module should always be something like: check for events, blit the background, blit constant stuff, blit sprites, flip screen - i have done this with as many as 100 sprites  and if anything it will require a delay to not go too fast so efficiency shouldn't really be an issue

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would recommend, based on personal experience. I built a tile-based game and over-engineered it a bit. My final solution looked a bit like this:

```
class Graphic(object):
    def __init__(*some_args):
        self.owner = which_object_owns_this_graphic
        self.priority = some_int
        # if more than one graphic are stacked on each other, which one to display?
        self.surface = surface_to_draw_on
        self.graphic = sprite_to_draw
    @property
    def x(self): return self.owner.x
    @property
    def y(self): return self.owner.y
    def draw(self):
        self.surface.blit(self.graphic, (self.x, self.y))

class Tile(object):
    def __init__(*some_args):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.graphic = some_default_Graphic_with_priority_minusone
        self.contains = [self]
        # list of objects that live here right now
    @property
    def topmost(self):
        """returns the graphic of the object with highest priority that is contained here"""

global_update_list = []
# anytime a tile is moved into or out of, place it here
```

Then in my event loop:

```
for tile in global_update_list:
    tile.topmost.draw()
global_update_list = []
```

That prevented me from having to redraw the screen every time something moved, and I could just redraw the tile it moved out of and the tile it moved into.